# .sh script error - compiling a .framework - macOS Sonoma (14.0)

Tags: ios

In one of the projects I have a .sh script that compiles a .framework

Since I updated to macOS Sonoma (14.0) it has stopped working, now it gives me this error:

`error: cannot compute path of binary 'Path(str: "/private/var/folders/xh/******/T/*****.iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/*** **.framework/*****")' relative to that of '/var/folders/xh/******/T/****.iOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/* ***.framework'`

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug with the latest Xcode, when running a compilation through the console it gives an error.

Try the following:

1. Download Xcode 14.3.1 from here https://developer.apple.com/download/all/
2. Unzip it and put it somewhere (don't overwrite your current Xcode)
3. In the console select this Xcode: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode_14.3.1.app (in the path put yours)
4. Launch the command again
5. When you have to use your normal Xcode, select the current Xcode again: In Xcode go to Settings > Location > Command Line Tools (select the last one)

Confirm to me that it worked for you

Comment: Refrain from doing this.
This is known bug in XCode 15, this happens if your build command has relative paths or symlinks. Follow the simple workaround mentioned here:
https://forums.swift.org/t/xcodebuild-create-xcframework-not-working-in-xcode-15-0/67439